# A unit-counit-like "adjunction" for partially-ordered sets

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, terminology, order-theory

Roughly speaking, two categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are isomorphic if there are functors $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ and $G:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ so that $F\circ G$ is the identity functor on $\mathcal{D}$ and $G\circ F$ is the identity functor on $\mathcal{C}$. (See [here](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2007/05/30/equivalence-of-categories/).)

I'm interested in a similar relation between categories that represent partially-ordered sets where $F\circ G$ is no greater than the identity functor on $\mathcal{D}$, and $G\circ F$ is no smaller than the identity functor on $\mathcal{C}$. Is this situation well-known? Does it have a name?

---

* I'm a complete newbie to category theory. Please take this into account when answering the question.

Comment: Do you know what an adjunction between two categories is? What you describe is a particular case, but since you put it between quotes I'm not sure you're aware of this.

Comment: @ArnaudD.: Is this particular adjunction standard? Where can I read more about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is precisely an adjunction between two posets. It's more commonly called a (monotone) [Galois connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection).

Indeed, the usual definition of an adjunction is a pair of functors $F,G$ as in your question, together with natural transformations $\eta:I_{\mathcal{C}}\Rightarrow G\circ F$ (the unit) and $\epsilon:F\circ G\Rightarrow I_{\mathcal{D}}$ satisfying the so-called "triangular identities" $G(\epsilon)\circ \eta_G=1_{G}$ and $\epsilon_F\circ F(\eta)=1_{F}$. But when the two categories are preorders, these identities are trivially satisfied, and the existence of natural transformations amounts to the conditions $c\leq GF(c)$  and $FG(d)\leq d$ for all $c\in \mathcal{C}$ and $d\in \mathcal{D}$. The bijection $\mathcal{C}(c,G(d))\cong \mathcal{D}(F(c),d)$ then tells you that $c\leq G(d)$ if and only if $F(c)\leq d$.

Comment: Thank you. This is extremely helpful. If I understand correctly, for $F$ and $G$ to form a Galois connection, we must assume in advance that both are order-preserving, right? Is there anything that we can say about a situation when only one of $F$ or $G$ is known to be order-preserving and in addition we know that the Galois connection formulas hold?

Comment: Yes, they must be order-preserving; this amounts to saying that they are functors. I don't know about the case where only one is order preserving, but I'll think about it.

Comment: @EvanAad If I give you a family of objects of $\mathcal D$ indexed by the objects of $\mathcal C$, let's write it as a (class) function $F$, and for each object $C$ of $\mathcal C$ I give you a natural isomorphism $\mathcal D(FC,-)\cong\mathcal C(C,U-)$, then there is a unique functor which has $F$ as its object part that makes the above natural in $C$, i.e. that is a left adjoint to $U$. When specialized to Galois connections, this means you can show that one of the adjoints is monotonic, even if it wasn't assumed, given that the other is.